# SharePoint 2013 workflow - lookup form parameter

Tags: sharepoint-2013, workflow, lookup, form-parameter

Using SharePoint Designer (2013), and creating a 2013 workflow I would like to create a dropdown "Initiation Form Parameter" but from values from another list.

Unfortunately, there isn't a "lookup" form type and the workarounds for SP 2010 workflows do not apply since that involves modifying Infopath (xsn) forms where as 2013 workflows create aspx files.

Any ideas and/or workarounds are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Custom the aspx page by JavaScript so you could retrieve data from SharePoint list(rest api or JSOM).

For example:
[image: 1][image: 2][image: 3][image: 4]